# Why am I getting csrf error in angular/play application

Tags: angular, csrf, playframework-2.6

My Angular client is sending the following `http` request

```
Accept      application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding     gzip, deflate
Accept-Language     en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection      keep-alive
Content-Length      44
Content-Type        application/json
Cookie      PLAY_SESSION=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1N…GFbZZRyEgXm2bH5xesZqEr9aJQJm0
Host        localhost:9000
Referer     http://localhost:9000/signup
User-Agent      Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; …) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0
```

Request url is `http://localhost:9000/ws/users/add`

But `Play` is rejecting this message with `403`. I see the following warning in `play` console `p.filters.CSRF - [CSRF] Check failed because application/json for request /ws/users/add`

What is the `csrf` issue here?

Comment: Interestingly, if I send a message using a 3rd party tool (like Postman), I get 200 OK!

Comment: do you have annotation `@CSRF.formField` in your play source?

Comment: It is not a play form. The UI is made in Angular5